# $mysqli query fails, foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

This insert command fails:

```
INSERT INTO posts (id, headline, content, post_date, blog) VALUES (default, 'Birds 
in Nepal are being Messed With', 'Have you heard about this? There are birds in 
the country of Nepal that are sitting around minding their own business, when out 
of nowhere they are getting messed with. Messed with!', curdate(), 'cost');
```

It dies with this error message:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint 
fails (`allanwebdev`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`blog`) 
REFERENCES `blogs` (`blog`))
```

There are two tables, one called 'blogs' and one called 'posts'.
'blogs' has one column called 'blog' which serves as a primary key:

```
DESCRIBE BLOGS;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| blog  | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

SELECT * FROM BLOGS;
+----------+
| blog     |
+----------+
| code     |
| politics |
| satire   |
+----------+
```

'posts' has a foreign key column called 'blog' which references the primary key in 'blogs'.

```
DESCRIBE POSTS;
+-----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| headline  | varchar(60)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| post_date | date           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| content   | varchar(64000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| blog      | varchar(10)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What. The heck. Am I doing wrong? Many thanks. This error message does exist elsewhere but invariably they are more complex problems. I'm operating simply and directly from a mysql command line.

Note that the sql call is being made from a php mqsqli object $db->query($sql). The actual string doesn't include a semi-colon at the end.

Comment: There is no key `cost` in `blogs`. And why not adding an auto-increment integer for primary key?

Comment: haha oh my god. you fixed my problem. 'code' was being generated by some quasi-dynamic html which the 'else' state erroneously defaulted to 'cost' instead of 'code'. I will look into incrementing the primary key. I am a front end developer attempting to broaden my horizons. Much thanks.